# Error occured with Mobility, Spina and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm working on a Rails project for my company. I want to implement Spina CMS on my Website. I started adding spina and mobility to the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'spina'
gem 'mobility', '>= 1.2.9'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
# For memory profiling
gem 'memory_profiler'
# For call-stack profiling flamegraphs
gem 'flamegraph'
gem 'stackprof'

# Use Json Web Token (JWT) for token based authentication
gem 'jwt'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'puma', '~> 5.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'rotp'
gem 'active_model_otp'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'webpacker', '6.0.0.rc.6'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'rswag-api'
gem 'rswag-ui'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'delayed_job_recurring'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'paranoia'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'foreman'
gem 'lograge'
gem 'ffi'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'delayed_job_web'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'ffaker'
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'interactor-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'
gem 'draper'
gem 'phonelib'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", group: :production
gem 'flipper-active_record'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.1.0'
  gem 'rswag-specs'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'active_record_doctor'
end

group :development do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen'
  gem 'licensed', require: false
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rename', '1.0.8'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', '0.17.0', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec'

  # No proper release for Rails 7 yet
  # Thus temporary https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/523#issuecomment-1008728997
  gem 'cucumber-rails', github: 'mathieujobin/cucumber-rails', branch: 'rails7', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 5.0', require: false
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Then I hit `rails g spina:install` on my terminal. But unfortunately, It's showing me the following error

```
/home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/mobility-1.2.9/lib/mobility.rb:133:in `translations_class': Mobility has not been configured. Configure with Mobility.configure, or assign a translations class with Mobility.translates_with(<class>) (Mobility::Error)
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/mobility-1.2.9/lib/mobility.rb:98:in `translates'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/spina-2.10.0/app/models/spina/resource.rb:9:in `<class:Resource>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/spina-2.10.0/app/models/spina/resource.rb:2:in `<module:Spina>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/spina-2.10.0/app/models/spina/resource.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `const_get'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `cget'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:26:in `block in ls'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `each_child'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `ls'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:232:in `block in eager_load'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `synchronize'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `eager_load'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `each'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `eager_load_all'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /home/shubharthak/Desktop/curve_tomorrow/rails-base/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /home/shubharthak/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am using RVM to get my ruby as 3.1.2 version If anyone knows how to resolve it please help me, I really need a help

Comment: Not familiar with any of this, but the README of Mobility says you need to write an initializer https://github.com/shioyama/mobility. By the looks of the error message, it seems that step is probably missing.

Comment: Thank you @XavierNoria for responding. I understand but where I need to write the initalizer and all ? there's no file created at all, *config/initializers/mobility.rb* is not created until I write rails g mobility:install and this command is not running. I am so confused and tried and tested lot of things but nothing seems working. If you can help me, that will be great

Comment: The description says you are running `rails g spina:install`.

Comment: Hey @XavierNoria Thank you so much i fixed it yes you're right it should `rails spina:install` only that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue, there was a problem in their Github Readme that I followed, the command I was using `rails g spina:install` is for the new project. but for existing project the command should be `rails spina:install` that will fixed the issue